# axis2 NullPointerException of ServiceClient.cleanupTransport() when creating and using pooled Client stub

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-axis

I am using axis2 1.5.4 to generate stub client to send soap message, as I known the axis2 is not thread-safe, so I use a pool to store stub instance. Each thread will borrow stub object from the pool before using and return it to pool after using. however, when the traffic is heavy(400 threads), there are always some NPE exception, it seems although the instance is already returned to the pool, it is still used by other thread. The exception stacktrace is as below:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.cleanupTransport(ServiceClient.java:824)
        at com.cmcc.aus.msgadpter.soap.security.SecurityClient.checkToken(SecurityClient.java:355)
        at com.cmcc.aus.service.esb.VerifyEaCallingTokenSvc.verifyEaCallingToken(VerifyEaCallingTokenSvc.java:81)
        at com.cmcc.aus.msgadpter.rest.VerifyEaCallingTokenRestInterface.postVerifyEaCallingToken(VerifyEaCallingTokenRestInterface.java:38)
```

And we also use cached http connection in the create of stub, the stub client code is as below:

```
public SecurityStub(java.lang.String targetEndpoint) throws org.apache.axis2.AxisFault {
        this(null,targetEndpoint);
        Options options = this._getServiceClient().getOptions();
        options.setTimeOutInMilliSeconds(60000);
        options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.REUSE_HTTP_CLIENT, Boolean.TRUE);

        MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager conmgr = new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager();
        conmgr.getParams().setDefaultMaxConnectionsPerHost(AusConstants.SECURITY_CLIENT_MAX_CONNECTION_NUM_PER_HOST);
        conmgr.getParams().setMaxTotalConnections(AusConstants.SECURITY_CLIENT_MAX_CONNECTION_NUM);
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(conmgr);
        options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.CACHED_HTTP_CLIENT, client);
    }
```

Can anyone provide me a resolution? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A comparison between the [1.5](https://github.com/apache/axis2-java/blob/bd5b18c3d34227d92a82093d49b7678c71906dcb/modules/kernel/src/org/apache/axis2/client/ServiceClient.java) branch and [1.6](https://github.com/apache/axis2-java/blob/1_6/modules/kernel/src/org/apache/axis2/client/ServiceClient.java) branch of the offending class reveal that the 1.6 version accounts for this. So a possible solution could be to just upgrade.